# Javascript date pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to create JavaScript pattern to see if input value is date, my date format is 2015/Jan/01, I have tried doing this `\d{4}/\[A-Za-z]{3}/\d{1,2}` but that did not work, Please help me in fixing it.

```
function SetValue() {
//  var newdata = document.getElementById('txtCellEditor').value;
    var myString = txtCellEditor.value;
    if (myString.match(\d{4}/\[A-Za-z]{3}/\d{1,2})) {
        alert("'myString' is date.");
}
```

Comment: Why such an unusual date format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `regex` is incorrect

1. Use delimiters of `regex` i.e. `/` at the start and end of regex
2. Use `^` and `$` to check exact match instead of substring
3. Escape the `/` by preceding them with `\`
4. No need to escape `[`
5. Use `test()` instead of `match`

**Visualization**

[image]

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/sA7nF1/1)

```js
var regex = /^\d{4}\/[a-z]{3}\/\d{1,2}$/i;

function SetValue() {
  var myString = document.getElementById('date').value;
  if (regex.test(myString)) {
    console.log("'myString' is date.");
  } else {
    console.log("'myString is not date.");
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="date" onkeyup="SetValue()" />
```

Comment: Good catch on the missing anchors.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the actual regular expression is fine, but you've forgotten to make it a regular expression by putting it in `/`s! (And you've escaped one of the `/` [but backward], but not the other.)

```
if (myString.match(/\d{4}\/[A-Za-z]{3}\/\d{1,2}/)) {
//                 ^     ^^           ^^       ^
//     regex quote-/      \--escaped--/        \-- regex quote
```